# installation error for paramiko received while building docker image

Tags: docker, pip, dockerfile, paramiko

I am trying to build a docker image using a dockerfile. Here are its contents:

```
FROM alpine 

ENV ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=False

RUN apk add ansible gcc python3-dev libc-dev libffi-dev openssl-dev
RUN pip3 install --upgrade paramiko
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

During the build process, I am getting the following error:

> /bin/sh: pip3: not found

> The command '/bin/sh -c pip3 install --upgrade paramiko' returned a non-zero code: 127

> Error: Process completed with exit code 127.

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to install pip3 using: `py3-pip` on your `RUN APK`:

```
FROM alpine 

ENV ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=False

RUN apk add ansible gcc python3-dev libc-dev libffi-dev openssl-dev py3-pip
RUN pip3 install --upgrade paramiko
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```